# How to insert a level in-between 2 levels in a multi-index?

Tags: python, pandas

E.g.

`df = pd.DataFrame({('X','A'): ['a','a','b'], ('Y','A'): [1,2,3], ('X','B'): [4,6,5], ('Y','B'): [9,4,2]})`

```
    X   Y   X   Y
    A   A   B   B
-----------------
0   a   1   4   9
1   a   2   6   4
2   b   3   5   2
```

Then I want to insert two redundant levels, one is the before the first level and the other is between first and second levels, such that

```
L1  V
L2  X   Y   X   Y
L3  W
L4  A   A   B   B
-----------------
0   a   1   4   9
1   a   2   6   4
2   b   3   5   2
```

Using `pd.concat` seems only inserting levels to the outermost level:

```
pd.concat({('V', 'W'): df}, names=['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4'], axis=1)
```

```
L1  V
L2  W
L3  X   Y   X   Y
L4  A   A   B   B
-----------------
0   a   1   4   9
1   a   2   6   4
2   b   3   5   2
```

, which is not what I want.

Comment: Is this just for visualization purposes? Adding indexes like that can make your life harder

Comment: I think, this will help you achieve, what you want - `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`

Answer (score 1):

For fun, you can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)/[`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.reorder_levels.html) :

```
out = (
    pd.concat({("V", "W"): df.rename_axis(columns=["L2", "L4"])}, names=["L1", "L3"], axis=1)
        .pipe(lambda df_: df_.reorder_levels(sorted(df_.columns.names), axis=1))
)
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

L1  V         
L2  X  Y  X  Y
L3  W  W  W  W
L4  A  A  B  B
0   a  1  4  9
1   a  2  6  4
2   b  3  5  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way by looping through the columns:

```
df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('V',k1,'W',k2) for k1,k2 in df.columns]),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   V         
   X  Y  X  Y
   W  W  W  W
   A  A  B  B
0  a  1  4  9
1  a  2  6  4
2  b  3  5  2
```